# PCI Compliance regex detect pattern with spaces

Tags: regex, symbols, credit-card, pci-compliance

I have to generate a regular expression to detect patterns of text where credit card numbers are involved, I have a regular expression but fails when the text is altered with simple spaces between the text for example (not valid credit card number):

```
4320 7589 9456 0123
```

The regex is:

```
4\d{3}(\s+|-)?\d{4}(\s+|-)?\d{4}(\s+|-)?\d{4}
```

This regex match easy, but if someone alter the text with spaces between any number like this:

```
4 320 7589 9456 0123
```

Does not match, I need a regex to detect any possible variable with spaces, special symbols, letters, some examples:

```
43 20 75 89 94 56 01 23
4 3 2 0 7 5 8 9 9 4 5 6 0 1 2 3
4320a7589b9456c0123
4320$7589$9456$0123
4320_7589_9456_0123
```

I don't know if I can strip any space, symbols from the pattern to analyze the text?

Comment: Try [`^4(?:\D*\d){15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/eH9qJ0/1)

Comment: `\s` will also match new lines. PCI compliance? I'm a bit worried when I see this...

Comment: @stribizhev works great! doesn't match the group but doesn't matter, because the pattern match.

Comment: @HamZa well when we speak about data loss is really disturbing when you look have people steals credit card information.

Comment: That data should never exist at rest in the clear, if it does there is no compliancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting because you actually asked for help with pattern to match any number of non-digits between the first `4` and 15 more digits.

The pattern is

```
^4(?:\D*\d){15}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH9qJ0/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `4` - literal `4`
- `(?:\D*\d){15}` - 15 occurrences of sequences of...

  - `\D*` - 0 or more non-digit symbols before..
  - `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string

If you need to capture, you can capture (like [`^4((?:\D*\d){3})((?:\D*\d){4})((?:\D*\d){4})((?:\D*\d){4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/eH9qJ0/2)), but the submatches will still contain the "junk" in-between digits.